# Searching for strings within file names using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, search, .doc

I've just started a new job, and we write reports for clients that are helpful for me to read to learn the ropes. I was trying to use PowerShell to pipe the titles into a text file, but unfortunately the company only standardised titles recently. This means that reports can be named anything, but having a look through the .docs, a lot of them have the word "report" in the title. Is there anyway that I could adapt my current commands to search more liberally for the word "report"?

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -include *.doc | Out-File P:\report.txt
```

Comment: Your search the word "report" in the file name or in the content of word document?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what you mean, and its not helping me with PowerShell, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Josh, that was a question, attempting to clarify what you meant.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry. :) I'm looking to search the filename, and only the filename. Most of these report are written in word, and I understand that reading the content of Word files in PowerShell is pretty cumbersome, so the filenames should give me enough results to lookover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most efficient version should be

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "your path here" -recurse -Filter *report*.doc | Out-File P:\report.txt
```

or if you only want the path in your file:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "your path here" -recurse -Filter *report*.doc |  Select -ExpandProperty Fullname | Out-File P:\report.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "your path here" -recurse -include *.doc | select-String "report" | out-file P:\report.txt
```

Comment: :( The computer didn't like that and started beeping. lol - everyone's looking at me now!

Comment: It kind of sounded like an alarm, my role isn't programming, so I'm wondering if it thought it was being hacked? Have you heard of that before?

Comment: No mate, I have no idea why your PC is acting like that.
So, did you use the -Path with P:\01_Contracts (2008-2013)???
make sure you place them inside the quotes, like this:
Get-ChildItem -path "P:\01_Contracts (2008-2013)"

Comment: I didn't set the path, looking at it. Thanks. I'm running it now, but it might take a while for it to filter through everything. I'll let you know how I get on. :)

Comment: For some reason it returned a bunch of gibberish, seemed to be working until I opened the text file. Thanks for the help though. :)